# detect browser close events in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-applications, browser

I am having a Web Page that looks like:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile = "~/Master11.master" CodeBehind="test7.aspx.vb" Inherits="MyApp.test7" %>

<%@ MasterType TypeName = "ASP.sample_template_master" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="mainContent1" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

When the user closes the browser, I want to display a confirm box if the user wants to save before exit.

If he says yes, then I wish to save the information in database and close the browser else I just close the browser.

I read msdn forums but all I found was window closing event which I was not able to apply here.

Please help.

Thanks,
krum_cho.

Comment: what's the difference for you between window closing and browser closing? anywho, you'll have to use javascript for this - you could always pass it back to VB.NET via AJAX if you really want to. Is there a reason you can't use JavaSCript?

Comment: @Thomas: Thanks. But I am not very well versed with Ajax. I thought of using javascript. But I could not come up with an event on which the function would be fired(Since I do not have a form here where I could have an event onClose()). I tried using window.closing event, but it is not supported for web application(atleast my class throws an error)   My test7.aspx.vb looks like  Partial Public Class test7
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

End Class

Comment: the onclose event is fired on the client side. It won't do any good to put it in your ASP.NET code that runs on the server. You need to put it in a script tag in the HTML.

Comment: I put some potential JavaScript code (tested in IE) that might help you in an answer. Let me know if you still need it to trigger in the CodeBehind.

Comment: Look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824421/detect-browser-close-on-asp-net/1824486#1824486).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following JavaScript statement.

```
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        if ((window.event.clientX < 0) || (window.event.clientY < 0) || (window.event.clientX < -80)) {
            alert("Child window is closing...");
        }
    };
```

Comment: @Thomas: Thanks. Is there any way I could transfer control to the codebehind file so that I can save the information in database.

Comment: Might try using JavaScript to submit the form...this is untested but: `document.<%=YourForm.ClientID%>.Submit()`

Comment: @Thomas: I really dont have a "form" all I have is a "content".This page is using a masterPage.

Comment: If you're using ASP.NET Web Forms, you have a form. Everything is inside it. check your Master Page and get the form id from there.

Comment: @Thomas: Instead of using form submit, can call any other method from my code behind? Something like 'PUBLIC SUB SAVEDATA()'

Comment: Your codebehind can never run if the page doesn't get posted back. That's why you use JavaScript to post the page back. Then you can save the data when you get the postback (just use `If Page.IsPostBack Then 'your code here' End If`

Comment: @Thomas: I used a button & set to visible = false. I had a button_click event in Codebehind that I fired from Javascript using var btid = '<%=Button1.ClientID%>';
                var bt = document.getElementById(btid);             
                bt.click();                                           It worked... Thanks for all your help!