# Insert datetime now in db field when session expire or browser closed

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008

When I login and check in the time, the time is inserted into db field through stored procedure. But when I logout or closed the browser checkout time not inserted (as not handle this) and when I login again the field remain checked In not checkout. How could I handle this in asp.net? When I logout or closed the browser I want to insert date Time now automatically.
[image]

Check Out time is inserted when I click on checkout link but I want the checkout time to insert when session expire or browser is closed.

Comment: The key is the session expire. By default, this is set to 20 minutes. Only after that time will the Session_End event be called. You can change this but I think you are lmited to 1 minute intervals. Be aware that changing the session timeout removes your session cookies after X minutes of inactivity (calls to the server).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have two questions:

1. How do I insert datetime now into the database when the user clicks `Check Out`?

   > Use the `DateTime.Now` value as a parameter to your stored procedure that inserts the check out value into the database table.
2. How do I handle the user clicking the `Check Out` or closing the browser?

   To handle the user clicking `Check Out`, just attach a click event handler to the server control (i.e. `LinkButton`'s `OnClick` property), like this:

   ```
   <asp:LinkButton id="LinkButton1" 
                   Text="Check Out" 
                   OnClick="LinkButton1_Click" 
                   runat="server"/>

   Sub LinkButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
       ' Call stored procedure and send DateTime.Now as check out value
   End Sub
   ```

   To handle the the user closing the browser, since this is a client-side event you can use JavaScript/jQuery or `unload` event, but a solution like [Detect Browser Close on Asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824421/detect-browser-close-on-asp-net) has its own drawbacks and problems. The safest approach is to handle the `Session_End` event in the `global.asax`, like this:

   ```
   Sub Session_End(Object sender, EventArgs E)
       ' Call stored procedure and send DateTime.Now as check out value
   End Sub
   ```